# Dlink dir-615 routerwith ubuntu 11.10

Tags: router

What instructions are available for configuring a Dlink dir-615 router with ubuntu11.10. I can access the router website and get a wired connection message but firefox cannot find the internet

Answer (score 1):

This kind of problem is probably not a problem with Ubuntu, rather with the router. Because this is a problem with the router, I would check out your router's User Manual, as there are setup instructions in there. If D-Link didn't include a print copy of the User Manual with your Router, [here's a link to it](http://www.dlink.com/-/media/Consumer_Products/DIR/DIR%20615/manual/DIR_615_Manual_RevA_v1_US.pdf):

I assume that you can view the PDF in some way, because you have to be connected to the internet to post to AskUbuntu.

You will have to reset your router before proceeding with the initial setup instructions in the manual. If you can not find a reset button in your router's configuration tool, there should be a reset button on the router.

Off-topic, but why are you still using Ubuntu 11.10? If you want to minimalize system upgrades, you can go to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, or you can stay at Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and still be fine for a while.

Answer (score 0):

to find your router. open settings (icon of gear and wrench) open icon marked "network" and look for the heading marked "default route".  Copy the default route and then paste it into a your browser.  It should take you to the router

If you have not changed the login the user should be either admin or user and the password may simply be pressing enter.  It is hard to tell.  I hate DLINKS as they are unreliable, short lived, and they are very inconsistent about things like logging in.  If someone offers you their old one of any other brand, even belkin, by all  means please take it.  I can help you order a netgear for only about $10.

If you don't need a router right now, please just connect your computer directly to the broadband modem until you can replace that piece of junk.